# Can't solve java NoClassDefFoundError but everything looks right... any ideas?

Tags: java, jar, package, directory

sorry in advance if I don't give enough information or if I'm unclear about anything, this is my first foray into using `.bat` and `.config` files.

I'm using a piece of academic software and am trying to add and run my own components.  the system uses a config file to launch a list of components (classes) required for the system using code like this:

```
semaine.components = \
eu.semaine.examples.swimmer.SwimmerDisplay| \
```

the system runs correctly and the specified components are initialised.

I add my own component to the list of existing components using the following code:

```
eu.semaine.examples.TestPackage.MyTest| \
```

however I get the following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:eu/semaine/examples/TestPackage/MyTest (wrong name: TestPackage/MyTest)

I've had a look around and it seems to me that I'm not doing any of the things which usually cause this error, e.g. my class name matches the file name it is stored in (public class `MyTest` is stored in `MyTest.java`), `MyTest` is in the package `TestPackage` and the folder in the file structure is also named `TestPackage`.

any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have asked for

```
eu.semaine.examples.TestPackage.MyTest
```

but say that you have placed the file in a directory called TestPackage.

Look carefully at the classpath specified in your batch file. My guess is that you have a directory hierarchy like this for the initial clash, rooted at that specified classpath

```
eu
  semaine
    examples
        swimmer
           SwimmerDisplay
```

in saying eu.semaine.examples.TestPackage.MyTest you are saying that the package will be "eu.semaine.examples.TestPackage" and the directory hierarchy will now be

```
eu
  semaine
    examples
        swimmer
           SwimmerDisplay.class
        TestPackage
           MyTest.class
```

I think you intend instead:

```
eu
  semaine
    examples
        swimmer
           SwimmerDisplay.class
TestPackage
  MyTest.class
```

and to say that the class is just

```
TestPackage.MyTest
```

not

```
eu.semaine.examples.TestPackage.MyTest
```

[In passing I agree that normal convention is not to capitalise package names, but I don't beleive that Java infers and semantic from the capitalisation.]

Comment: Hi, I have everything in a jar and the folder hierarchy is as follows: myJar>eu>semaine>examples.  examples contains the swimmer folder (containing SwimmerDisplay.class) and the TestPackage folder (containing MyTest.class). I will try changing the package name to lower case just incase.

Comment: I think your TestPackage folder should not be in the examples directory, but rather in the root of the Jar, and you should adjust how you reference it as I show in my answer. Look at your code, if it says package "TestPackage" then I'm pretty sure I'm right.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your class is not in the application's classpath when it's started. You mention `.bat` files. If that's how you start the application, then it should contain a section where the classpath is assembled. It must contain the parent folder of the `TestPackage` folder so that the JVM knows where to find your class file.

Answer (score 0):

Naming convention states that package names must be all lower case, see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html.

I guess the jvm thinks that TestPackage is a class and MyTest is an inner class.

Comment: changed the case so it reads "testpackage" but this hasn't helped.